# Git - is the garbage collector allowed to run in parallel?

Tags: c, git, garbage-collection

I have a threaded C program which launches `git gc` via `popen` in a pthread alongside the main application. The main thread launches other git commands.

**There are no problems for most of the other git commands except when I commit via `git commit -m "msg"`.**

For some reason while it is commiting and then the other thread tries to run the garbage collector in parallel, the application crashes.

However, doing a git commit and a git gc on the terminal at the same time via `git gc &! git commit -m "msg" &` seems to work most of the time, but a few times the commit process exits with exit code 128.

Maybe this is the problem? How do I ensure the garbage collector runs successfully in parallel? Is the garbage collector meant to be run in parallel?

I found this mailing list thread also but it doesn't seem to be too informative: https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg02138.html

Comment: Why do you run `git gc`?

Comment: @CodeWizard Because I need to optimize the repo so the other commands are faster, I run it every 30 min

Comment: I don't know about the multithreading capabilities of GIT, but If it is only the GC command, why don't you use a [read/write lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)? Exclusive lock for gc, shared lock for all other operations?

Comment: I do not really know what the [tag:c] has to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're doing **A LOT** of git manipulations like `git commit --amend` or `git rebase` or creating a lot of objects, launching `git gc` so often is useless. Please take a look at the [git gc NOTES](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#_notes):

> On the other hand, when `git gc` runs concurrently with another process, there is a risk of it deleting an object that the other process is using but hasn’t created a reference to. This may just cause the other process to fail or may corrupt the repository if the other process later adds a reference to the deleted object.

Maybe instead of launching `git gc` in parallel, you should just tweak it to your needs?
Configurations is done with [`git config gc.*`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-gcaggressiveDepth), in particular `gc.auto`.

Comment: Note also that if one is automatically running `git gc` in the background, one should run it as `git gc --auto`. This sets up the usual 14-day (or otherwise-configured) grace period to avoid the problem quoted above.